# How to host and access murmur (mumble server) on OpenShift without port forwarding?

Tags: openshift

I wanted to experiment with hosting a tiny murmur server, up to a few people.

Using a diy cartridge template, and a static build of murmur.x86, I've been able to start Murmur on the allowed OpenShift IP address.

However, how, if there's any way, would I be able to access the actual murmur server from a client, without requiring SSH > Port Forwarding from mine (and anyone else's who may want to access) local PC?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to expose ports other than 80/443/8000/8443 publicly on OpenShift Online.  You are also able to make raw TCP connections to those ports, you can only use http/https/ws/wss.  The only way to access the ports that murmur uses is over ssh port forwarding.  If you would like to run a murmur server you would need to use a virtual machine that has it's own ip address and all ports exposed.

Comment: Thank you. Then would a (complicated) possibility be to recompile murmur/mumble to use wss protocol (if allowed by the source code terms, of course, that's not related to the question), or would it for any reason be impossible to use wss for custom applications?